# Using PHP/SQL, how do I store and retrieve comments stacked/nested under each other?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Imagine the following sutation:

```
Comment ID 1
|
|--- Comment ID 2 (reply to ID 1)
     |
     |--- Comment ID 3 (reply to ID 2)
     |
     |--- Comment ID 4 (reply to ID 2)
          |
          |--- Comment ID 5 (reply to ID 4)
```

[(example in action)](http://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/l44l2/i_wasnt_lying_when_i_said_i_will_cherish_this/)

How do I store the above into SQL so that I can retrieve and list it later?

I'm relatively good in PHP/SQL, but this situation is recursively killing my head. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is all about data modling rather that php or mysql.

You could represent this into a tree structure. Just think that a comment just needs to have a parent. Each comment, one parent. However the first item in the tree (the root element) won't have a parent)

So, to model this in OOP you would use a class Comment that will have itself associtated and the name of that relationship will be is_child_of. One of them would have a null value. If you want to get a step further into this solution check the [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) ;)

Regarding the database model, you just need a table Comments that will have whatever you need about them plus a field called is_child_of. So each comment will have a father but every comment on the highest level of the tree.

As comments have an order, (in your example it wouldn't be the same to swap comments 3 and 4) you should take into account that you will have to sort them in some way (ID if it is an incremental value or a datetime).

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You could store your data as a [nested set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). This is a very common way to represent tree-like data in a SQL table.

Comment: Sounds good, could you please provide a simple example? I've never done this.